# Calculating rate of decay of a material in python

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I have to calculate rate at which a material is decaying. I have set of 5 measurements of the material over a period of 5 years. Below is my approach:-

I have added initial as well as the testing uncertainties as noise using monte carlo method.

Initially I have assumed the rate to be linear, using np.linalg.lstsq I have calculated the rates, essentially slope of the line.

Now I want to calculate the rate assuming rate is accelerating curve, decay is more when material loss is more.

This is something like:-

```
np.random.seed(0)

x_data = np.linspace(0, 5, num=50).reshape(-1,1)

# function something in the form of y = variable^x, taking variable value as 
#1.1 below
var = 1.1
y_data = np.power(var, x_data)

plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
plt.scatter(x_data, y_data)
plt.show()
```

I looked at np.polyfit  & curve_fit options, still trying to figure out to calculate the rate.

Comment: Rates are most likely exponential functions of the form A*exp(x/b), where b is your rate. Try to fit that with curve fit.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **curve_fit** method from **scipy.optimize**.  An appropriate model for fitting is the exponential decay function; however, the curve_fit method will estimate the parameters of any function.

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot

def decay(t,b,c):
    # A = initial amount
    # B = decay constant
    # t = time
    # C = additive constant
    x0 = 100
    return x0 * np.exp(-b * t) + c


t1 = [10,20,70,100,110] # experimental time data
y1 = [80,75,78,44,46] # experimental final amount data

# use curve_fit to estimate B (decay paramter) and C (additive paramter)
params = curve_fit(decay,t1, y1)

pyplot.plot(t1,y1) # actual
pyplot.plot(t1,[decay(i,*params) for i in t1]) # predicted

pyplot.show()

print(params)
```